# Positive vector in the kernel of an antisymmetric "adjacency" matrix

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, skew-symmetric-matrices

For $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, let $V=[[1,n]]$, and $G=(V,A)$ be an oriented graph, stronlgy connected with $n$ vertices. Let $M\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})=(m_{i,j})$ be an skew-symmetric matrix of size $n$ and rank $r$, such that for all $i,j\in V$: $i\longrightarrow j\Longleftrightarrow m_{i,j}>0$ (hence $M$ is a kind of adjacency matrix for $G$). Is there any necessary and sufficient condition on $G$ and $r$ assuring that there exists a positive vector in $\text{Ker}(M)$?

I've tried several matrices for $n\in\{3,4,5\}$ and it seems that, given $G$ and $r$, the fact that there exists a positive vector in $\text{Ker}(M)$ does not depend on the values of the coefficients $|m_{i,j}|$ when they are non-null, but I do not know how to predict that such a vector exists. I have just noticed that given $G$, the answer of the question can vary with $r$.

Comment: If both $i \to j$ and $j \to i$ exist then the matrix can never be skew-symmetric. Are you explicitly forbidding such double edges?

Comment: The graph $G$ is oriented. So if $i$ and $j$ are connected, either $i\rightarrow j$, or $j\rightarrow i$.